# How can I combine an elif and if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to make a an app that can see if you are old enough to drive and if you have a license, however I want to combine them together so both the conditions have to be true before it says you can drive a car. My code is

```
is_old = True
is_licensed = True

if is_old:
  print("You are old enough to drive")
  
elif is_licensed:
  print("You have a driving license")
  
else:
  print("You can't drive")
```

I want to combine the if and elif together. I'm really struggling on this and help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if is_old and is_licensed:`

Comment: Oddly enough you have answered your own question. What do you know about binary logic?

Comment: You don't "combine an if and elif" to represent a situation where both conditions are true. `if X: do x_actions; elif Y: do y_actions` _by definition_ means the `Y` condition is only checked if the `X` condition is not true

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user is not old enough and/or doesn't have a license? That'll tell you how to lay out the program. For example, should it just say "You can't drive", or should it be more specific, like for example, "You are old enough, but don't have a license"? **Edit**: Samwise's approach is good, but there are other ways if you want.

Comment: No I just want to say You can't drive

Comment: I don't know anything about binary logic except binary is 0 and 1, I also know how to write numbers in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if is_old and is_licensed:
  print("you can drive")
else:
  print("you can't drive")
```

Comment: if is_old and is_licensed:    AND operator is used where there are 2 if statements (nested) i.e.
if(){
  if(){
  }
}

Comment: OP said "both the conditions have to be true before it says you can drive a car."

Comment: I'm quite new to python so it's a bit hard to understand what more advanced people are saying.

Answer (score 3):

`elif` is short for "else if" -- since it's an `else`, it only happens as an *alternative* to the preceding `if`.  That is, your `elif is_licensed` will only happen if the preceding condition (`is_old`) was false, and the final `else` will only happen if *both* preceding conditions were false.  Only *one* of the three `print` statements will be executed -- that's the essence of an `if/elif/else` chain, only the first matching condition takes effect.

What you want is an `and` condition:

```
if is_old:
    print("You are old enough to drive")

if is_licensed:
    print("You have a driving license")

if is_old and is_licensed:
    print("You can drive")  
else:
    print("You can't drive")
```

In the above code, the two `if`s are independent -- both can be true, one can be true, or neither can be true.  You might get two, one, or zero lines of output from that section of the code.

The final `if/else` is based on *both* conditions being true, because of the `and` in between them.  If you're old enough `and` you have a license, you can drive; otherwise, you can't drive.  You will get exactly one line of output either way.

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like you are saying that I can use an and keyword to do what I want?

Comment: I also said it outside of the code: "What you want is an `and` condition."

Comment: @snowhow It looks like you missed boolean operations in the tutorial or couldn't find them in the [language description](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). Just follow the link.

Comment: That makes sense next time I will look at the python documentation first. :)